# this.$http.post not working in vue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, vue-resource

I use vue-resource to make a post request like this:

```
methods: {
        searchNodes: function (val) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$http.post('/search_query', [val]).then(function (response) {
                this.nodes = response.data;
                this.loading = false;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is my route

```
Route::post('search_query', 'SearchController@search')->name("search");
    Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
```

and in this is my function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

put in network tap it return status code 302 and redirect me to the login page?

Comment: Are you required to be logged in to access the route?

Answer (score 2):

Just add {emulateJSON:true} as a third parameter after data you want to send with request.

```
this.$http.post('link-to-api', data, {emulateJSON:true}).then(function(response){
    // Do something with the response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that i was forget to include this line at the top of my script:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
```

Answer (score 0):

2 years, 7 months ago  I hope you have already found this solution

Import vue-resource.js to your code:

This is the link : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1

**code vueJs:**

```
methods: {
   searchNodes: function() {
        this.$http.post('YourBackEndpath/', 
          { dataArray:this.colsArray } ).then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.data);
        });
    }
}
```

**code PHP/laravel:**

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    print_r($post['dataArray']);
```